# Rails using 'where' to search association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select all `Notices` that belong to the `Character` via the `has_one` association that have a `nil` `supernotice`. How do I code this?

notice.rb:

```
belongs_to :character

has_one  :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                       foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                       dependent: :destroy
has_one  :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship,
                       class_name: "Notice",
                       source: :commentee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :active_comment_relationship

has_many :passive_comment_relationships, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                         foreign_key: "commentee_id",
                                         dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, through: :passive_comment_relationships,
                    class_name: "Notice",
                    source: :commenter
```

character.rb:

```
has_many :notices

def topNotices
  self.notices.where(supernotice: nil)  # doesn't work
end
```

Logs:

```
: SELECT "notices".* FROM "notices" WHERE "notices"."character_id" = $1 AND "notices"."commentee_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "notices"."created_at" DESC
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 316ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column notices.commentee_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."notices" WHERE "notices"."character_id" = $1 AND "notices"....
```

The logs show the error `notices.commentee_id` does not exist, but I've clearly stated in `notice.rb` that a notice `has_one :supernotice through: :active_comment_relationship`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The foreign key in `active_comment_relationship` and the source in `has_one :supernotice` are different values. If the foreign key is `commenter_id` then the source would be `commenter`.

Comment: I've just added more detail to `notice.rb`. I don't believe this is the problem.

Comment: `:supernotice` is a relation made through `active_comment_relationship` which depends on `foreign_key commenter_id`. But you have said the source of `supernotice` as `commentee`. So it checks for the `commentee_id` instead of `commenter_id`.

Comment: Similar, if not identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244411/rails-where-clause-for-associations

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
has_many :notices
```

In your `character` model.

Comment: I do apologise, I did have `has_many :notices` in my character model, I forgot to put it in the question. I've messed this question up.

Comment: I'm afraid my problem is not solved. I've edited and improved the question. The logs show Rails is searching for `notice.commentee_id`, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your association in the first place.

When you define associations between two models, you have to set up properly in both of the models.

In your `notice.rb` Model, you have `belongs_to :character` association, so you have to define the counterpart of this association in your `character.rb` Model as well. You have to define a `has_many` or `has_one` association in your `Character` model which in your case is `has_many notices`.

So, in your `character.rb` Model, you need to define this association:

```
has_many :notices
```

When you setup the associations in both the models properly, then you can expect to get the correct result using:

```
self.notices.where(supernotice: nil)
```

because now it knows how your `Character` model is associated with your `Notice` model.

I highly recommend you to read the [Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I do apologise, I did have `has_many :notices` in my character model, I forgot to put it in the question. I've messed this question up.